# Component Render Issues (Long Read)

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I am dynamically getting data from my database to display on my website but I've encountered a problem and don't know how to fix it.

I have a main Home page which loads in a bunch of tiles that you can click on and take you to another page on my SPA. Some of the tiles you can click on can render STL objects from a file or some tiles will not when clicked on.

I have encountered an issue with my components that render STL files.

## Issues?

1. Clickable Component is Multi Rendering my Model Component (or something like that?)
2. I have unmount and remount `<Model/>` for each page view?
3. General Issue with Project Setup?
4. Issue with STL (Model) component ***can be found at the bottom***

## Provided

1. Home.js (main component)
2. ClickableImage (component that returns [])
3. Layout.js (dynamic content pages)
4. Model.js (Component that loads my model)
5. Reproducible Code Current Issue [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-khorana-bnbf7)

## Updates

`11:03pm Feb 23 : Added in CodeSandBox`

codesandbox code explanation.  2 Images are displayed, clicking on first image will take you to a layout that doesn't load in the STL file. The second image does. That's when everything breaks.

In Model.js under `/src/components/Layout/

### Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        const {projects} = this.props;
        return (
            <section className="max-container">
                <div className="home-layout">
                    <div className="grid pl-4 pr-4">
                        <ClickableImage projects={projects}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

### ClickableImage

```
const ClickableImage = ({projects}) => {
    const mappedData = projects && projects.map((project, index) => {
        return (
            <Link to={'/project3D/' + project.projectId} key={index}>
                <img
                    src={project.banner}
                    alt="img" className="clickImage"/>
            </Link>
        );
    })

    return (
        mappedData
    );
}
```

### Layout.js (/project3D/)

```
...
<div className="content-div">
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 10, 100] }}>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <Model url={"./RaspberryPiCase.stl"} />
        </Suspense>
        <OrbitControls />
    </Canvas>
</div>
...
```

So that is my general layout of everything on my page.

Home -> Click Image -> Layout Page.

Now this is where things get a little weird.

The `Canvas` portion on my layout page gives me this error when trying to load it.

```
Uncaught invalid array length react-reconciler.development.js:7648
```

```
The above error occurred in the <Model> component:

Model@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2430:15
Suspense
Canvas@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:137042:66

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

But when I copy the Canvas section to my `Home Component` it will render my STL file with no problem and then it will also load my STL file on my other page as well.

Here are images to show you the problem without pasting `<Canvas>` in my home component.

### PreHome Paste

[image]
[image]
[image]

### After Pasting Canvas in Home Component

[image]
[image]

### Model.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import {STLLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader";
import {useLoader, useThree} from "react-three-fiber";

export const Model = ({url}) => {
    const geom = useLoader(STLLoader, url);

    const ref = useRef();
    const {camera} = useThree();
    useEffect(() => {
        camera.lookAt(ref.current.position);
    }, [camera]);

    return (
        <>
            <mesh ref={ref}>
                <primitive object={geom} attach="geometry"/>
                <meshStandardMaterial color={"orange"}/>
            </mesh>
            <ambientLight/>
            <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]}/>
        </>
    );
};
```

I just looked into it some more but apparently useLoader is what's most likely throwing my error, and I don't know why. (Only know this because when I comment it out the errors go away)

lmk if more info is required.

Comment: where is that `useLoader` coming from? Also you don't have any dependency on `useEffect()`, wich means it will run each time you re-render. Is this fine?

Comment: `useLoader`  is coming from `react-three-fiber` i added in the import statements. Also updated `useEffect` with the the camera dependency. Still same issues even after these changes `Error: invalid array length`

Comment: can you please share  a reproducible example, expanding a bit that CodeSandbox you've shared? Looks like some issue related to navigation and rendering/disposing of the image. A high-fidelity demo that reproduces the error will be of help.

Comment: will get on that. Will update when done

Comment: @tmilar https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-khorana-bnbf7

Comment: The code-sandbox is not reproducing the issue right away, are you sure it's correct? I had to fiddle with the `<primitive>` obj to use the `geom` ref from `useLoader`. Can you check? Also, the `./book.stl` file in this case, it's not included, can you upload it as well, trying to mimic the same project folders structure?

Comment: whoops. I fixed up the code. Now it gives the same issue. I forgot to remove that bit and fix it to use `useLoader`. I also updated it with the file.

Comment: You shouldn't use indexes as keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `useLoader()` is having issues fetching the file you are providing in the `url` variable.

In your example, the value you end up providing as "url" is `"./RaspberryPiCase.stl"`.

To fix your issue, simply provide the full absolute URL where your STL file can be fetched from.

Based on your provided Codesandbox, it's on your project `/public` folder, so a simple way to fix your issue is doing:

```js
export const Model = ({url}) => {
    const fullUrl = `${window.href.origin}${url.replace(".", "")}`;
    const geom = useLoader(STLLoader, fullUrl);
    // ...
```

[See it live](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-ardinghelli-09oov?file=/src/components/Layout/Model.js) on a fork of your Codesandbox.

Additionally, you can follow [this discussion](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-loader-issue-invalid-typed-array-length-4/13442) in case your actual resource URL was not actually public (ie. required some kind of authentication). In that scenario, you can fetch the resource `.gtl` file first as an arrayBuffer, and then pass it to your loader.

Comment: gotta be kidding me, it was the `.`. Thank you very much.